# Symfony console Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'communication.PRIMARY'

Tags: symfony, doctrine, constraints

got a problem that drives me crazy.

I use symfony 6.2 with doctrine.
My entity is defined like this

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CommunicationRepository::class)]
class Communication
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;
...blabla more fields
}
```

The data table is defined like

```
create table if not exists communication
(
    id              int auto_increment
        primary key,
...more fields here
}
```

And it is empty(!) not one damned record in it.
Now my code is:

```
$obj = new Communication();
$obj->setSender($givenSender)... blable setting data
$this->emMessaging->persist($obj);
$this->emMessaging->flush();
```

The $this->emMessaging is an EntityManager fetched from doctrine.

What I get now is

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'communication.PRIMARY'
```

There is no id written in the statement and even if I would write a zero to it... There is no duplicate, because the table is empty!
When I debug into that stuff, get the sql and execute it in a shell, the record is written correctly with a valid id.

I've done this kind of code hundreds of times... It all works. This part always fails.

Comment: I would assume, that your code somehow adds two communications in the same transaction (maybe something references another communication?) and fails with the second, but rolling back both. However, just to be sure, could you look in the profiler (assuming this happens on a request) to see which db queries are run? the "generated value" apparently also doesn't generate a proper value. you might need to set the [strategy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/attributes-reference.html#generatedvalue) explicitly

Comment: Profiles give the following statements :
4  21.77 ms  "START TRANSACTION"
5  73.24 ms  INSERT INTO communication (parameters without id) VALUES (questionmarks as placeholders)   And then, of course, the values for the parameters
6  47.11 ms  "ROLLBACK"
So there is only one statement with one insert an this fails immediatly. 
I tried to set strategy to identity which didn't change anything.

Comment: in that case, I would seriously consider running `CommunicationRepository::findAll()` because it sure sounds like there is something in the database ;o/

Comment: Honestly I was looking on the wrong db (my colleague moved it and didn't check the env properly and did not realise the difference between env and target). When I switched to the right one, the auto_increment flag on the id was missing. Unfortunately that didn't help, but setting the strategy explicit (as you mentioned) finally did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, did not find a way to mark it as solved